# Cant get bourbon files imported in my site (show tree in post)

Tags: css, bourbon

I believe a picture best describes my issue

https://postimg.org/gallery/37bdm2lp8/

Please see img for tree document

https://postimg.org/image/qsmm9rdx1/

My issue is a simple one, but I am not getting my main.sass which imports all the other sass files to for compiling to display the bourbon assets, so   my site isnt rendering the bourbon assets

I have tried the basic `@import ../css/1-tools/bourbon` but that doesnt work

Any help appreciated as the css isnt working now :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are all ready using gulp, try using the actual Bourbon NPM package. You can add it to your `package.json` file and require it via your `gulpfile`.

- How to: https://github.com/thoughtbot/bourbon#installing-with-npm-and-using-a-node-based-asset-pipeline
- Here is the page for the Bourbon package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bourbon
- Here is an example `gulpfile` that uses bourbon (with some other stuff you can probably ignore): https://github.com/thoughtbot/bitters/blob/master/Gulpfile.js

The main parts of this example `gulpfile` that you would need to add are the `require` on [line 1](https://github.com/thoughtbot/bitters/blob/master/Gulpfile.js#L1) and adding bourbon to your Sass `includePaths` on [line 17](https://github.com/thoughtbot/bitters/blob/master/Gulpfile.js#L17).

---

*edit* ⤵

Once this is set up you'll want to change your sass import to the following:

```
@import "bourbon";
```

Because of the addition to `includePaths`, `gulp-sass` will know where to look.